# Send mouse events to inactive and hidden windows/WPF forms

Tags: sendmessage, postmessage, user32, microsoft-ui-automation

I'm developing an app that needs to generate mouse events on a window Win32/WPF which may be minimized or hidden from view on the desktop.

I have tried the user32.dll APIs SendInput, SendMessage, PostMessage etc. These work only if the window is visible on the desktop. Would you know about any methods that work for hidden/inactive windows?

I've also tried .NET's UI Automation library. In this case, a window is brought to the front or I'm not able to get a clickable point for the control.

Any ideas how I can proceed? If I can proceed?

Comment: 2 days and counting... No comments?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still interested in an answer (I just stumbled upon this question out of sheer dumb luck), but have you tried making a global windows hook?

I have no honest idea on how to properly go about implementing one; but I know you should be able to add a global windows hook to, well, Windows, to listen for whatever events you want (should include mouse and keyboard events!)

Good luck...

Comment: Thank you @Serge. I did solve the problem eventually.
The window form (WPF) is now a TCP client to my app which sends the mouse coordinates. I find the control and use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(eventHandler, eventArgs).